# Uso y origen de las "canas verdes"

Tags: etimología, modismos, chile

En Chile si te disgustas una y otra vez te salen *canas verdes*. Por ejemplo

> Este profesor me está sacando canas verdes.

¿Se usa esta expresión en algún otro país?

¿Tiene alguna explicación u origen?

Comment: Según [la RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=79wHJk7) se usa también en Perú y Uruguay. La expresión no la conocía pero suena graciosa.

Comment: [La referencia más antigua](https://books.google.es/books?id=dEARAQAAIAAJ&q=%22canas+verdes%22&dq=%22canas+verdes%22&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjB9err2dvNAhVIWRoKHS1NA344ChDoAQgtMAQ) que he encontrado: _"[...] porque en el mejor de los casos, con todo mi derecho, tal vez ganaría el pleito, pero me quedaría en la calle lo mismo y me llenaría de **canas verdes**, me amargaría para siempre el corazón [...]"_

Comment: En España no recuerdo haberlo oído.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Iba a escribir un comentario pero me salía demasiado largo. A ver qué tal con estas hipótesis:</sub>

Antes de nada: En España no recuerdo haberlo oído.

Leo en [WordReference](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/%C2%A1me-van-a-sacar-canas-verdes.667173/?hl=es) que se usa también en México y, probablemente, toda Latinoamérica. En [un blog argentino](http://weblogs.clarin.com/revistaenie-elmisteriodelaspalabras/2011/01/27/sacar_canas_verdes/) también lo mencionan y [dan un posible motivo](http://weblogs.clarin.com/revistaenie-elmisteriodelaspalabras/2011/01/27/sacar_canas_verdes/#comment-595):

> Supongo que la idea de lo imposible es el secreto de la frase.

Siguiendo con los comentarios de esta última página vi que alguien hablaba de su acepción en el DRAE, por lo que finalmente me di cuenta de que esta expresión viene indicada en...

> [**cano, na**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=79wHJk7)
>   Del lat. canus.
>   1. adj. canoso.
>   2. adj. De color blanco. U. m. en leng. poét.
>   3. adj. desus. poét. Sabio o experimentado por viejo.
>   4. f. Cabello que se ha vuelto blanco. U. m. en pl.
>   (...)
>   ***sacar canas verdes a alguien*
>
>   1. loc. verb. coloq. Perú y Ur. Causarle preocupación y disgusto continuos.**

Por lo que podemos determinar que, como mínimo, se utiliza en México, Perú, Uruguay, Argentina y Chile. Tal variedad de países da a pensar que probablemente se usa en todos. Para probar, busqué si se usa en Colombia y resulta que sí. [Jergozo](http://jergozo.com/significado/sacar-canas-verdes/en/colombia) indica que quiere decir *Desesperar , abrumar*.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu investigación, tal parece que ya encontraste toda la información que existe. Voy a dejar abierta la pregunta un tiempo antes de aceptar tu respuesta, por si alguien descubre otro origen. La frase debe ser muy antigua, la referencia de Carlos Alejo es de 1892.

Comment: @Rodrigo faltaría más. Es incluso mejor dejarla sin aceptar para que capte más la atención de futuros usuarios. En otro orden de cosas, me pareció muy curioso el uso de _tal_ en _tal parece que..._. Nunca lo había oído.

Comment: Pensándolo bien, tal parece que es un error :)

Comment: Es habitual el "_tal parece que_". En las primeras líneas de una búsqueda en Google aparecen una canción de Romeo Santos (norteamericano, _tal parece que mi amor crece y crece_) y otra de Wason Brazobán (dominicano, _tal parece que yo me acostumbré a ti en un solo día_). Y un titular del mexicano Siglo de Durango: _Tal parece que no tiene remedio la justicia mexicana_. Y yo soy chileno. Vale decir, _tal_ parece que los diferentes son ustedes los europeos.

Answer (score 0):

En Guatemala también se usa esta expresión.

Comment: Bienvenida a [spanish.se]! Gracias por su respuesta, seria bueno si tiene una referencia, o simplemente decir que esta es tu experiencia personal.